# while performing dual operation on UIImageView

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

This time I am facing problem while performing dual operation on UIImageView means

```
1) Zoom+Flip the Image 

2)Zoom + Reverse the Image 

3)Zoom + Flip or Reverse + Rotate(+- 90)deg
```

so please help to find out the solution of this problem. In thiscase for Zoom I use the GuestureRecognizer for fliping+Revesing+Rotating UIImageView I Use the the UIButton for these operation so how I can handle these operations wiith combination on UIImage

what exact the problem When I Zoom In or Zoom Out the image the at the same time I want to rotate (+-90 deg) or Flip or Reverse the Image at exact zoom In or Zoom Out Position but that time Image get reset then perform the respective operation such rotate, flip ,reverse I wanted to do it simultaneously on UIImage

my code as

```
if (btnNames == "Rotate R") 
 {
 Angle = deg + 90;
 imgview.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation (Angle * (float)Math.PI / 180); 
 return Angle;
 } else
 { 
 Angle = deg - 90; 
 imgview.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation (Angle * (float)Math.PI / 180); 
  return Angle;
```

## }

For Reverse

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale (-1, 1); 
imgView.Transform = transform;
return  true;
```

============
For Flip

```
if (flips == false) 
 { 
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale (1, -1); 
 imgView.Transform = transform; 
return  true; 
 }
```

this code i implemented it works fine individually perform to operation. But I want to work simultaneously on UIImage

Comment: Help us help you. You do not describe what problem your facing (missing description), nor how you tried to achieve those actions (e.g. code). Answers will be much more helpful if they do not have to guess those information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

- Place the `UIImage` in a `UIScrollView` with zooming setup
- Modify your `UIImage`'s `Transform` for reverse, rotate, etc.

To setup zooming:

```
yourScroller.MaximumZoomScale = 5;
yourScroller.MinimumZoomScale = 1;
yourScroller.ViewForZoomingInScrollView = _ => yourImage;
```

An example for rotation would be:

`yourImage.Transform.Rotate (Math.PI / 2)`

Play around with it, the `UIScrollView` should modify the same `Transform` on the image, so everything should work in tandem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand what you mean, but it sounds like your trying to do more the one transformations for an image by setting the `UIView`'s `transform` property like this (example):

```
myView.transform = scale;
myView.transform = flip;
myView.transform = rotate;
```

What happens then is, that only the last one of these "is active: on the view.

What you should do is "keeping/saving" the current transformation and appending the new one with `CGAffineTransformConcat` like:

```
myView.transform = scale;
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(myView.transform, flip);
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(myView.transform,rotate);
```

Keep in mind that for some transformations order of concatenation matters!

Answer (score 0):

Transformations can be combined by applying them to an existing transformation:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

// Rotate
if (btnNames == "Rotate R") {
    Angle = deg + 90;
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, Angle * (CGFloat)Math.PI / 180);
} else {
    Angle = deg - 90;
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, Angle * (CGFloat)Math.PI / 180);
}

// Reverse
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);

// Flip
if (!flips) {
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1, -1);
}

// Apply combined transformation
imgView.transform = transform;
```